# Counting total records vs status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to do an update for a batch when all the jobs for that batch are completed. To do this I want to compare the total number of jobs vs the total completed. I'm doing that with the query below, however it's a pretty slow query. Any suggestions to improve this? Or alternate ways to approach the main update?

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.BatchId, 
    j.JobStatusId,
    COUNT(j.BatchId) OVER(PARTITION BY j.BatchID, j.JobStatusID),
    COUNT(j.BatchId) OVER(PARTITION BY j.BatchID) 
FROM [Job] j 
ORDER BY j.BatchID
```

Index only on JobID (PK)
[image: Explain Plan]

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? Also what does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Sorting takes almost 65%. In update you don't need ordering and distinct. So remooving both is the first step.

Comment: "To do this I want to compare the total number of jobs vs the total completed."  Why?  Why not just query for what you want: batches that have no incomplete jobs?  It seems like a waste of time to count everything.

Comment: Because it's friday and I really need a beer. Thank you @BaconBits for being the logical voice of reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<<<< THIS IS NOT TESTED >>>>

Assuming that JobStatusId describes the Status like this:

```
0 = completed
1 = running
2 = error
```

You can try these two queries, don't know which one is faster just give it a try:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT j.BatchId AS CompletedJobs
FROM    Job j
WHERE   NOT EXISTS( --running jobs or jobs who ran into an error
            SELECT  TOP 1 1 
            FROM    Job j2 
            WHERE   j2.BatchId = j.BatchId
                    AND j2.JobStatusId IN (1,2))
```

OR this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT j.BatchId AS CompletedJobs
FROM    Job j
        LEFT JOIN
            --running jobs or jobs who ran into an error:
            (SELECT j2.BatchId
             FROM   Job j2
             WHERE  j2.JobStatusId IN (1,2)) j2 ON j.BatchId = j2.BatchId
WHERE   j2.BatchId IS NULL
```

Your original query has to order a lot (which ends up in bad performance most of the time.
Working a lot with databases in the past years showed me: ordering is only needed in 2% of the queries where i saw an "order by" clause. Maybe even in 1% ;-)

DISTINCT, ORDER BY, COUNT OVER PARTITION,... will never be a fast operation - if you combine them you see whats the result.

Comment: I'm going to give you the answer. This is pretty much what I ended up with. I was having a really braindead day that day.